# Why is it that convergence almost surely and convergence in the r-th mean norm do not necessarily imply each other?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Why is it that convergence almost surely and convergence in the r-th mean norm $L_r$ do not necessarily imply each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Almost sure convergence does not imply convergence in the $r$th mean. For example, consider $X_n:=e^n\chi_{(0,n^{-1})}$ where $(0,1)$ is endowed with the Lebesgue measure. $X_n\to 0$ everywhere but not in the $r$th mean.

  What is used here is that $X_n$ can take very large values on small sets, so that we have the almost sure convergence but the $r$-th moment can be arbitrarily big.
- Convergence in the $r$-th mean implies almost sure convergence *of a subsequence*, but not necessarily of the whole sequence. Consider indeed for each $N$ a partition $\{A_{N,1},\dots,A_{N,N}\}$ of $(0,1)$ of measure $1/N$ and take $X_n$ the indicator function of $A_{k_n,n-k_n}$, where $k_n$ is the unique integer such that $\sum_{i=1}^{k_n}i\leqslant n\lt \sum_{i=1}^{k_n+1}i$: there is convergence to $0$ in the $r$th mean, but not almost everywhere. The subsequence $\left(X_{k_n}\right)_{n\geqslant 1}   $ converges to $0$ almost everywhere.